# IK Arm Rigging with more than 3 bones

Tags: rigging

I have an exported model from 3ds Max, it was rigged with CAT.
The main problem is that the CAT skeleton has lower arm roll bones that linked **consistently** (*UpperArm* -> *LowerArm* -> *LowerArmRoll* -> *Hand*).

[image: That's how it looks]

So, i don't understand how to make IK rig properly, because that hierarchy obviously screws up IK solving.

Any thoughts? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Ccould you please give more details, for example what does it do that you don't want? If you want to constraint the rotation of some of the bones, you can select the bone and in the Properties panel > Bone > Inverse Kinematics, give some Limits

Comment: Well, my problem is that the roll bone obviously bends when IK is applied.
I'll check the limit section, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you're trying to limit the rotation between the 2 lowerarm bones, what you're looking for is probably the *IK Limits*: In *Pose* mode, select the bone you want to constrain, go in the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Inverse Kinematics* (this menu appears as soon as the bone is influenced by an IK), then limit on the axis you want, in that case X and Z.

As you mentioned, in 2.8 you can simply click on the *Lock IK* option (top of the same menu).

[image]

Comment: Yeah, i just did what you show and it works like charm! 
Actually, i'm using Blender 2.8 and it has simple "Lock IK" button for each axis.

I've also added "Copy Rotation" with one axis, so the hand bone rotates the roll bone.
Thank you!

Comment: maybe you should dig into switching your armature to B-Bones display and segment your bones

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't make any fundamental changes to skeleton. What's the advance of using B-Bones?

Comment: it will allow to segment your bone and therefore twist it differently and bend it smoothly, but it needs some tests to make sure it's an advantage. If your character is rigid, maybe not

Comment: Briliant, been searching the entire day for a solution to this, in Maya was possible to use a Pivot point to move the effector point, but in Blender your advice seems the way to go.